# How to add view to UIWindow so that existing view controller gets pushed up

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I am dealing with **no internet view** and trying to achieve what **Youtube ios app** shows no internet view. I am able to replicate it to some extent but the problem is the no internet view is added to current UIWindow which is getting shown but as a subview. The current view controller view is not pushed up like its done in **Youtube ios app** .  I searched in SO also about how to push it up so that **UIWindow**'s last view becomes the no internet view.People suggested to have a controller as **rootViewController** and add the no internet view to it. I did the same but no internet view was shown but rest of the view controller was white. How to achieve the same mechanism like **youtube** one?

Below is how I am currently doing it

```
if netStatus == .NotReachable {
    print("The internet is down.")
    noInternetView.removeFromSuperview()
    noInternetView = NoInternetConnection(frame : CGRect(x: 0,y: self.window!.bounds.height - 15 ,width: self.window!.bounds.width,height: 15))
    noInternetView.LabelErrorMessage.text = "No Connection"
    noInternetView.LabelErrorMessage.backgroundColor = UIColor.black()

    let window=UIApplication.shared().windows.last
    window!.addSubview(noInternetView)
    internetStatus = .NotReachable
}
else {
    print("The internet is working!")
    noInternetView.LabelErrorMessage.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex : "#008000")
    noInternetView.LabelErrorMessage.text = "Back online"
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5) ) {
        self.noInternetView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: You want transparent view ?

Comment: no I want view with color. only the no internet view which is in size of (window width,15)

Comment: shown but rest of the view controller was white ?

Comment: yes when I tried to do with rootViewController of the app delete window.

Comment: Sorry but it is quite unclear to . me. `NoInternetConnection` is UIView that you want to add when internet is not available. and also you want things behind should be visible  transparently that what you want  ?

Comment: I want to add nointernet view to the window as the last view of the window so that other views in the window is pushed up.currently my no internet view is overlaping with the other views

Comment: what is your purpose / idea behind that approach ? It is not good practice to add view to the UIWindow directly.

Comment: I am trying to achieve what Youtube ios app is doing. In youtube app if there is no internet then a subview is added to bottom of the screen and other views are pushed up above it.that view is visible from everywhere.I don't think they are adding it in each view controller, perhaps they are adding it in UIWindow from AppDelegate

Comment: If you observe only bottom tabbar is just moving all of the controller are at the same place

Comment: you can keep this no internet view in your viewController and get an outlet to its height constraint and change it when u want show or hide the view.